# Should not allow single zero or 0.##

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

How do I restrict single zero in a numeric (Decimal may alow) textbox? Textbox can accept any number but it should not accept only zero or "0.##" as value.

For example: "900.55", "200.00" is valid but "0" and "0.105"is invalid.

I tried `^[1-9]\d\.?\d[0-9]*` but it accepting the "0" and "0.##"

Comment: Are you sure? I am pretty sure that your regex does *not* accept `0`, since it does not start with [1-9].

Comment: Looks like it will accept `12.3` but not `123.4`

Comment: If the `TextBox` is going to accept only numbers, why don't you try to parse its `Text` property to `double` then see if it's `>= 1`?

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to do this: `float.Parse(textBox1.Text) < 1`?

Comment: @VimalStan That's what I've been saying already. Besides, `float.Parse` may crash if the input cannot be parsed to float. It would be better to use `float.TryParse` instead.

Comment: @Nolonar I've already posted an answer that uses `TryParse`.

Comment: @VimalStan I see. I haven't read the answers, sorry.

Answer (score 6):

You're almost there.

```
^[1-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?$
```

The input must

- start with a number 1-9
- be followed by any sequence of 0-9
- and optional:

  - a dot followed by one or more 0-9.

---

Notes:

1. This also disallows `3.`. If you don't want that, replace the last `+` with a `*`.
2. You can use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`. I've used the latter to stay consistent with `[1-9]` and keep things simple.

Comment: Or ^[1-9]\d*\.?\d*...
(you might want to allow the dot w/o anything following it, btw)

Comment: @Viv your regex would not allow "5", for example.

Comment: Eh... we're grinding water here... Just use something like http://myregextester.com/ w/ proper options and sort it out. Pretty sure mine works allright.

Comment: @BrianStephens Yes it wont, Only commented cos I was wondering why Greg using \d just made the last match char group [0-9]

Answer (score 1):

I think you're close, but it may be easier to include the decimal and following digits in a group and make that entire group only allowable once like this one:

```
^[1-9][0-9]*(\.\d*)?
```

Also, here's a useful site for testing [regular expressions](http://regexpal.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be simpler to do this:

```
float result;
return float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out result) && result < 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the textbox only accepts valid numbers, and all you want to assert is that it is > 0. All you really need then is

```
^[1-9]
```

or if trailing prefix zero's are allowed

```
^0*[1-9]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could alternatively write it using a negative lookahead:

`^(?!0\b)\d+(\.\d*)?$`

This has the added bonus of accepting numbers with a preceding `0` like 022.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same situation and solve this.
try out it.

> @"[^0]*[0-9].\d{2}$